# splitting the column using Regex in R

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a character data of the type

```
a[1:5]  
"Tampa Bay Buccaneers / 1st / 1st pick / 2015" 
"Tennessee Titans / 1st / 2nd pick / 2015"      
"Oakland Raiders / 1st / 4th pick / 2015"      
"Washington Redskins / 1st / 5th pick / 2015"  
"New York Jets / 1st / 6th pick / 2015"
```

Q1. I want to break that column into four separate columns and store
each in your data frame.Eg:

```
Tampa Bay Buccaneers, Tennessee Titans ... in data frame1 , 
1st, 1st, ... in data frame2
1st pick, 2nd pick, ... in data frame 3
2015, 2015, ... in data frame 4
```

Q2. We need another data frame that has the number in it and all the text removed in the variable "a". 
Eg: 112015, 122015, 132015 and so on.

I am stuck with Regex. Please help.

Comment: Please let me know if anything is unclear in the question.

Comment: have a look at `?strsplit`.

Comment: Yes I tried strsplit but i got confused in the split argument, how shall I put "/" into the split argument.

Answer (score 1):

We can split the 'a' vector using `" \\/ ")` to a `list`, `rbind` it and convert to a data.frame.

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(a, " \\/ ")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If we need multiple data.frames, `transpose` the `list` output ('lst'), convert each of the `vector` in the `list` to `data.frame`, change the `list` names and use `list2env` to create multiple 'data.frame' objects in the global environment (though not recommended)

```
library(data.table)
lst <- transpose(strsplit(a, " \\/ "))
list2env(setNames(Map(function(x,y) setNames(data.frame(x),y) , lst, 
        "Col1"), paste0("df", seq_along(lst))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
 df1
#               Col1
#1 Tampa Bay Buccaneers
#2     Tennessee Titans
#3      Oakland Raiders
#4  Washington Redskins
#5        New York Jets
```

#### data

```
a <- c("Tampa Bay Buccaneers / 1st / 1st pick / 2015", "Tennessee Titans / 1st / 2nd pick / 2015", 
"Oakland Raiders / 1st / 4th pick / 2015", "Washington Redskins / 1st / 5th pick / 2015", 
"New York Jets / 1st / 6th pick / 2015")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. But Now I wish to split it into 4 data frames. the ouput is something like                                                                                                                                                    V1  V2         V3
1   Tampa Bay Buccaneers 1st   1st pick
2       Tennessee Titans 1st   2nd pick
3        Oakland Raiders 1st   4th pick
4    Washington Redskins 1st   5th pick
5          New York Jets 1st   6th pick
6          Chicago Bears 1st   7th pick
7        Atlanta Falcons 1st   8th pick
8        New York Giants 1st   9th pick

Answer (score 1):

```
a<-c("Tampa Bay Buccaneers / 1st / 1st pick / 2015", "Tennessee Titans / 1st / 2nd pick / 2015",
"Oakland Raiders / 1st / 4th pick / 2015" , "Washington Redskins / 1st / 5th pick / 2015" , "New York Jets / 1st / 6th pick / 2015")

library(stringr)
library(plyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Q1<-do.call(rbind,str_split(a, "/"))
Q1b<-apply(Q1,2,data.frame)
Q2<-as.data.frame(gsub("[A-Za-z///]+[[:blank:]]","",a))
```

Answer (score 0):

The stringr package has a couple of useful functions: str_split and str_split_fixed.

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(str_split_fixed(a, "/", n=4))
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. library(stringr)
y = data.frame(str_split_fixed(a, "/", n=4))
Can you tell me how can we access the variable inside "y' as four other columns are created inside y ?

Comment: The result is a dataframe 4 columns wide by n long.  Access to the values is by the typical index mechanisms: y[i, j], where i indicates row and j the column.  I suggest reading: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html